# Two Different Ways of Designing a Rule (Detecting Tokens Like ##<Text>##)

Tags: antlr4

I'm designing a grammar for a markdown based language but without the context awareness.

For example I want to detect tokens like ##  ##.

I found two different ways of designing rules for that and I'm not quite sure which way could be the best approach.

The first way: Defining more complex tokens and a simple rule.

```
fragment
HEAD
    : '#'
    ;

fragment
HEADING_TEXT
    : (~[#]|'\\#')+?
    ;

SUBHEADLINE
    : HEAD HEAD HEADING_TEXT HEAD HEAD
    ;
```

---

```
subheadline
    : SUBHEADLINE
    ;
```

Due to the fragments HEAD and HEADING_TEXT would get to the parser. I'm prototyping within IntelliJ and the parsing works well. And the errors message show something like "missing SUBHEADLINE" what's great for the main application (I think I can change those errors easily to human readable ones).

The second approach: Much simpler tokens and more complex rules for the parser.

```
HEAD
    : '#'
    ;

HEADING_TEXT
    : (~[#]|'\\#')+?
    ;
```

---

```
subheadline
    : HEAD HEAD HEADING_TEXT HEAD HEAD
    ;
```

Works fine, too. The errors are more specific and maybe not very good for transforming them to human readable ones.

But I'm overall not sure which approach I should follow and why?! The more complex tokens are easier to write in this case because there won't be any complex rules like normal programming languages contains. But it don't feel like this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways have their own behavior and it depends on what you need to decide what to use. Defining the subheadline in the lexer the way you did does not allow skipped/hidden tokens between e.g. '#', which is probably what you intend. Doing that in the parser instead allows to have e.g. `# /*acomment*/headline##` which is probably not the intended behavior. Also I would combine things that strictly belong together into one rule. For instance HEADING_TEXT in your second variant may match input that you want to have matched in a different way. Instead define the subheading exactly as the language dictates:

```
SUBHEADING: '##' .*? '##';
```

This is even conciser than your simpler variant while still not allowing skipped input between the markers.

Comment: Thanks! Made this clearer to me. I'm stuck with other things but this is okay now.